# Why isn't this performing a system command?

Tags: ruby, linux

I've put this together through scripts that I have found online, but I'm not sure why my puts command is not performing a system command?  It just sits in the terminal unexecuted.  When I tried system ("rspec spec") it worked but I wasn't able to capture the output.

```
def run(cmd)
  `#{cmd}`
end

def run_spec_files
  system('clear')
  result = "rspec spec"
  puts result
  growl(result)
end

def growl(message)
  growlnotify = `which growlnotify`.chomp
  unless growlnotify.empty?
    title = "Test Results"
    options = "-w -n Watchr -m '#{message}' '#{title}'"
    run("#{growlnotify} #{options} &")
  end
end

watch( 'lib/(.*)\.rb' )      { run_spec_files }
```

Comment: The answer to your direct question has already been given but you might just consider using autotest with the autotest-growl.  Accomplishes all of this without all of the manual definition.

Comment: I used to, but autotest just stops working after awhile.  Watchr seems to stay vigilant longer for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`puts` Just prints out the string you pass it. It doesn't execute it in a shell. Backticks like in your `run` method will execute on the shell. Try this:

```
def run_spec_files
  system('clear')
  result = run("rspec spec")
  puts result
  growl(result)
end
```